# Multiple errors on iOS project (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks

I have really been struggling with build errors on my Xcode project which has completely stopped me from making any progress (since I can't test anything).

The project was made using Xcode 7.0 beta 4 (7A165t) on OS X El Capitan, with Swift (2.0).

A lot of the errors I've been getting (including these ones I think) have been due to my struggle with importing 3rd-party frameworks/libraries, such as RevealViewController [GitHub][1] and YouTubePlayer [GitHub][2].

**1st error**: "Command /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1".

I did find another post here on StackOverflow but the solution they had did not work for me.

**2nd error**: "Command /usr/bin/ditto failed with exit code 1".

Could not find a solution that worked for me online.

**3rd error**: "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

**4th error**: "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: can't open file: /Users/Leonard/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Golden_Words-bykzmptkoohvzgfcowmdynxuxekn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Golden Words.app/Frameworks/YouTubePlayer.framework/YouTubePlayer (No such file or directory)"

This error seems to have to do with a framework I am using called YouTube Player.

Here is a Dropbox with screenshots relating to my problem (build error logs). Stupid StackOverflow won't let me post screenshots because of my low reputation...

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l7l736nl2bfwcvt/AAA-e0-8FUpvqJmAEgwgA1nAa?dl=0

Included are also the links to the GitHubs of the frameworks I'm using.

Please help me fix these errors so I can get back to making progress... I can't do anything right now...

Comment: Did you test in stable xcode version?

Comment: Did you try to clean the project and delete `DerivedData`?

Comment: Running the project in Xcode 6.4 gives me even more errors. Cleaning the project does not help fix the errors (nor does deleting DerivedData)

Comment: Xcode7 beta5 is out, you could try downloading that and rebuilding, seeing if anything is cleaned up but doubtful.  It looks like some of these errors might be a result of the others, does the first one give you any more info about it?

Comment: I still get the same errors on beta 5 :S